# What is the wingtip station number on a Boeing 747?

Tags: wing, boeing-747, fuselage

[image: example of station number]

In the figure we can see the station line even though it is not clear. I'am using that picture just for an example to make the question clearer.

**Main question**

- What is the station number for wingtip on a Boeing 747? (fuselage station and water lines)(If possible the butt lines too)

I tried searching the internet for the station number and couldn't find what I'm looking for. Or am I looking at the wrong place to find it? Where to find the number if you don't have access to the aircraft maintenance manual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the wing tip station , just divide the wingspan by two and multiply by 12.  The stations are in inches.  For a 747 with a 195' 8" wing span, the tip station is 195.66 divided by 2, times 12 = 1173.96, so the tip will be Station 1174.

For X and Z you need to know where the datum point is longitudinally and for the X axis, and what the waterline is that defines the Z axis.  Waterline is often the cabin floor.  X datum on a jet is often the forward pressure bulkhead surface.

Comment: can you give an example position for the water lines and butt lines

Comment: Look up the SE post What Is The Coordinate System Used On Aircraft, from about 3 years ago.

Comment: Strictly speaking, wouldn't Station 1174 be one twenty-fifth of an inch _beyond_ the wingtip?

Comment: This is incorrect as wing station on a swept wing aircraft generally follows a line parallel to the sweep on the leading edge starting at BL0.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had the chart of this from Boeing’s MDF on the 747, but a good estimate might be as follows.

A Boeing 747 has a wingspan of 195 ft 8 in and a LE sweep of 37.5°.

Therefore:

Span (in): 2348 in
So wingtip lies on BL 1174.

The wing station uses a different coordinate system for swept wing aircraft which is parallel to the wing LE or similar datum.  Using the wing LE as a datum, this gives:

1174/cos(37.5°) = 1479.79

So the wingtip would be at WS 1479.79

NOTE: this is a reasonable estimate and not to be taken